# Login as user, render view from ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I want to email users the rendered html of a particular controller action signed in as a particular user. Not sure how to render an email html entirely from an controller action with session information. Doing this in a background task (delayed_job). Any way to render an arbitrary controller action in an ActionMailer?

Answer (score 0):

I would add some metadata to the background task you create (be this with `delayed_job` or with resque) that saves the id of the current user in your controller.

In delayed job in particular you can use a custom job: any object with a `perform` method can be a job. So create a `MailerJob` class, and in your controller do `m = MailerJob.new` and add the id of the current user. In your `perform` method you can do a `find` for that user and grab whatever you need.

It's important that you just put the id of the user into your `MailerJob` class, as ActiveRecord objects usually don't serialize all that well (or at one point in the past didn't serialize that well).

Comment: passing the id is not the problem. I'll need to login as the user in the delayed_job and render a particular controller/action from the MailerJob. I basically need something like

```Ruby
class MailerJob < Struct.new(:username)
  def perform
    user = User.find_by_username(username)
    signin user
    #somehow visit say BooksController#index with :user_id = user.id
    #get the rendered html and pass it to mailer:
    UserMailer.list_of_books(:body => the_html_from_rendered_books_controller_index_action).deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: I would suggest just repeating your books query in the mailer and some of the HTML in the mailer view you render. Because (a) you'll want to provide a plain text version of your email OR because viewing HTML in mail clients is not like viewing HTML in browsers (I think you have to do more CSS inline and may need to change your CSS and/or layout around for a correct experience).

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use a background worker in this case. If you use sessions, you can utilize the user's session to access that objects data.

I commonly write out this in the application controller file:

```
def set_current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end

def require_current_user
  set_current_user
  redirect_to root_path unless @current_user
end
```

The depending on which controller you want to actually use the mailer, you can just pass the @current_user object and pass in custom HTML based on the object.

Comment: I want every monday to login as each user and send them a list of their books as it is rendered at /:user_id/books. this is a cron not a user request.